# getting meteor do work in docker + commiting and then rerunning issue

Tags: meteor, docker

**The short version:**

I basically have an image that i run and within that I run a meteor app. But then when I commit this image and then run this new image my app does not run. Can Anyone advise what I am doing wrong? Or how I could trouble shoot this?

**The long version:**

I have the following docker images:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
meteor-todos        0.1                 30bd0cd18781        3 days ago          840.6 MB
```

here I am running my image:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 meteor-todos:0.1 bash
root@5c04458cc81c:/#
```

here i create my meteor app that I am trying to follow [here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app):

```
root@5c04458cc81c:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@5c04458cc81c:/# meteor create simple-todos
Created a new Meteor app in 'simple-todos'.

To run your new app:
  cd simple-todos
  meteor

If you are new to Meteor, try some of the learning resources here:
  https://www.meteor.com/learn
```

It creates the simple-todos directory, so I `cd` and run the app with the command `meteor`

```
root@5c04458cc81c:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  simple-todos  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@5c04458cc81c:/# cd simple-todos/
root@5c04458cc81c:/simple-todos# meteor
[[[[[ /simple-todos ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
^C
root@5c04458cc81c:/simple-todos#
```

But if I then exit this container and the commit it as an image. And then run the new image I cannot get the app to run I get errors. Anyone help me understand this? not sure if it is a meteor thing, a docker thing or just me and my environment?

get the id of the container that is running (using another boot2docker terminal):

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
5c04458cc81c        meteor-todos:0.1    "bash"              30 minutes ago      Up 30 minutes               0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   dreamy_yalow
```

exit the container

```
root@5c04458cc81c:/simple-todos# exit
exit
docker@boot2docker:~$
```

commit the container, and this is shown using `docker images`

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker commit -m "meteor tut start" 5c04 meteor-todos:0.2
8442afe92d2f50ac75f2a537b69472010f2bf8c101539b3598aa5ae72c65e735
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
meteor-todos        0.2                 8442afe92d2f        6 seconds ago       930 MB
meteor-todos        0.1                 30bd0cd18781        4 days ago          840.6 MB
```

Now if I run the image again

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 meteor-todos:0.2
```

my simple-todos dir is still there, so i change director and run the app giving the command `meteor`. Can anyone advise me on this error?

```
root@ac7d1be3b145:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  simple-todos  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@ac7d1be3b145:/# cd simple-todos/
root@ac7d1be3b145:/simple-todos# meteor
[[[[[ /simple-todos ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.

/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.ltydx3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^
Error: EXDEV, rename '/simple-todos/.meteor/local/build'
    at Object.Future.wait (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.ltydx3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
    at /tools/fs/files.js:1331:28
    at Object.wrapper [as rename] (/tools/fs/files.js:1334:20)
    at Object.files.renameDirAlmostAtomically (/tools/fs/files.js:812:11)
    at Builder.complete (/tools/isobuild/builder.js:571:13)
    at /tools/isobuild/bundler.js:1913:13
    at /tools/isobuild/bundler.js:1930:7
    at /tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2205:22
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:268:13
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:261:29
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:259:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:250:23
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:114:14)
    at Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:249:19)
    at Object.exports.bundle (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2047:31)
    at /tools/runners/run-app.js:551:36
    at time (/tools/tool-env/profile.js:232:28)
    at Function.run (/tools/tool-env/profile.js:377:12)
    at bundleApp (/tools/runners/run-app.js:541:34)
    at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (/tools/runners/run-app.js:594:35)
    at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (/tools/runners/run-app.js:858:28)
    at /tools/runners/run-app.js:396:12
    - - - - -
root@ac7d1be3b145:/simple-todos#
```

**NOTE** I am using a boot2docker on windows7

**EDIT1** what I have to do to get it working

To get it to work(in the new image)  I have to do the following: 
But I do not want to have to delete it and rebuild it every time. I want to be able to commit it and run it as a container in the background.

```
root@ac7d1be3b145:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  simple-todos  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@ac7d1be3b145:/# rm -rf simple-todos/
root@ac7d1be3b145:/#
root@ac7d1be3b145:/#
root@ac7d1be3b145:/# meteor create simple-todos
Created a new Meteor app in 'simple-todos'.

To run your new app:
  cd simple-todos
  meteor

If you are new to Meteor, try some of the learning resources here:
  https://www.meteor.com/learn

root@ac7d1be3b145:/# cd simple-todos/
root@ac7d1be3b145:/simple-todos# meteor
[[[[[ /simple-todos ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Started your app.
```

Comment: Please, elaborate title of the question, it's not clear